# Run Ansible from local system on remote hosts which are behind Bastions

Tags: ssh, ansible, devops, bastion-host

I have multiple hosts and all of that hosts are behind their own bastion host, So every server has its own bastion host. Because of the single-tenant structure.
Now I want to run a command or playbook on all of these servers which are behind bastions.

Comment: I use to do ssh like this- ` ssh user@IP -J user@bastion`

Comment: You can use jump hosts in the config of your hosts in the inventory.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Can you please help in that. Because every server is behind its own bastion host. and I want to run command on all hosts via ansible.